# Nielsen and Chuang - 4.22

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I’ve been struggling with this exercise for a while now. I realize that one must use the decomposition of a unitary gate $U$ as $e^{i\phi}AXBXC$ where $A,B,C$ are unitaries s.t. $ABC=I$. Nevertheless, I can’t seem to write up a circuit that gives an identity sequence of gates e.g. $ABCCBA=I$ when either of the two control qubits are 0, and $U$ in its decomposition otherwise. Perhaps I am approaching this incorrectly?

> The questions asks to prove that a $C^2(U)$ gate can be constructed using at most 8 one-qubit gates and 6 controlled-NOTs.

Comment: Hi Faris and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hi John. I just checked the Meta and it does not appear to say that homework-type questions won’t be answered. I’ll make sure this independent study question fits with the guidelines though.

Comment: For the identity sequence of gates, couldnt you just chose A=B=C=I ( with I=I_1 tensor I_1). If not, maybe uou.can provide much more needed detail, so.one.could.answer.you Q without consulting the book. When you say 'the question' do yiu mean your question or the priblem.in the book.

Comment: No, that does not work. That assumes that $U=I$. The point is that arbitrary $U$ can be decomposed as above and we can design a circuit just keeping in mind this assumption (i.e. no suppositions about $A,B,C$ other than being unitary). Note that $X$ is the Paul $x$ matrix. I'll update my question so it's clearer... Sorry about that

Comment: A hint: I think I remember that you need to use the square root of $U$ to do this.

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/how-to-reduce-circuit-elements-of-a-decomposed-c2u-operation